# is CocoaPods "pod install" working

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

How can I check if "pod install" command of CocoaPods is actually downloading pods or not?
It seems doing nothing, it's about 10 minutes it's status is :
**Analysing Dependencies**

Comment: Quit terminal and open up your workspace if you are using cocopod plugin then quit Xcode and open up it again.

Answer (score 5):

`pod --verbose install`  appears the be the command that will show you more.

This is a list of the options for the pod command

```
Options:

    --silent     Show nothing
    --version    Show the version of CocoaPods
    --no-color   Show output without color
    --verbose    Show more debugging information
    --help       Show help banner of specified command
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a verbose command so it tells you each time it's doing something, `download Bolts`, `installing Bolts`, etc...

Have you made sure your cocoa pods install is up to date.

```
gem update cocoapods
```

from the commend line.

If that doesn't work... what's in your `Podfile`?

Comment: just these in my pod : 
pod "MBProgressHUD"
pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor', '~> 1.2.3'
pod 'Shimmer'

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if "pod install" command of CocoaPods is actually downloading pods or not

Use the **Activity Monitor** to check whether the Terminal is receiving data.

But when it show Analysing Dependencies, it actually do nothing about downloading. All you can do is waiting.